# Android Dialog: Where do I return after dismissing the dialog?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

I'm opening an alert dialog from an activity using the 'onCreateDialog' method:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog = null;
        switch(id) {
        case DIALOG_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION:
            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            final View passwordDialog = factory.inflate(R.layout.password, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            alert.setTitle("Please enter your password");
            alert.setView(passwordDialog);
            alert.setCancelable(false);
            alert.create();

            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new PasswordDialogListenerOk(
                    passwordDialog, getApplicationContext()));
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new PasswordDialogListenerOk(
                    passwordDialog, getApplicationContext()));

            alert.show();
            break;
        default:
            dialog = null;
        }
        return dialog;
    }
```

Everything works fine and smooth, but I have no clue WHERE I'm getting back in my ACTIVITY. The dialog disappears, but where is the return point in the activity after the dialog dismisses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a distinct "where" for returning back to the activity. It does go to `OnResume` at some point I suppose, but if you're looking to just do something once the dialog is dismissed, you should just put that code in your listener (in this case you've called it `PasswordDialogListener`). If there's something specific you want to use it for, you should explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: In the listener, I call the server in order to verify the password entered by the user in the dialog. After the password is verified, I want to go back to the activity and change the value of a TextView element. I cannot update this element in the listener as I don't have access to it.

Comment: So give your listener access. There are a number of ways to do it. If your code in your listener is not async, you could wrap your `PasswordDialogListener` in another listener which updates the UI after the inner listener is done. You could pass in a callback to your listener, you could make your listener an inner class, or you could pass a view to your listener for it to be updated (just make sure you don't leak it).